# SharePoint 2013 CSS to remove hover text from radio button

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, choice-field

I have a survey where the options are shown via radio buttons.  When you hover over the buttons, you can see text.  I'm trying to come up with CSS that will not show the text when you hover over the radio buttons.  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I don't think "show text when hover radio button" is default SharePoint behavior. There are many ways to hide the text. One approach is modify your customization. Another is type a "space" as your radio content.

Comment: Unfortunately, the content must be there, but not visible on hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript code to hide the tooltips in surveys, edit the page and insert a content editor web part, paste the code below and save the page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.ms-RadioText').removeAttr('title');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot - Thanks!

Comment: Looking forward for your feedback.